# Nested if else statement in R

Tags: r

I have a variables x

```
x <- c("adsad", "assdf", "gfdfg", "vbcvb")
```

If x having character ds then b =0 elseif x having character fg then b=1 elseif x having charcter bc then b=2.

I have this variable in a dataset and have around 100(i have given only 4 in the example) records.

I am just creating a new variable b whenever we see those string available in the variable X. I mean it need to search the character that i have mentioned each row of the variable X and based on that assign values to variable b

Comment: If `x` has `ds` and `fg`, what is the value of `b`?

Comment: If it has both b will be 3

Comment: And if `x` has `dsfgbc`?

Comment: we can assign it to b 5....Iam just giving an example

Comment: Could you give us more detail about your data, and what we are trying to achieve? What is the next step?

Comment: @63549 Please edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37136064/edit to put in the additional information from your comments.

Comment: I am just creating a new variable b whenever we see those string available in the variable X. I mean it need to search the character that i have mentioned each row of the variable X and based on that assign values to variable b

Answer (score 2):

If we need to create arbitrary groups based on number of matches from the lookup then maybe we can try this:

```
# data
x <- c("adsad", "assdf", "gfdfg", "vbcvb", "dsXXfg", "xxdsbc", "dsfgbc")

# lookup list
lookup <- c("ds", "fg", "bc")

#result
data.frame(x = x,
           group = 
             order(
               apply(sapply(lookup, function(i) grepl(i, x) * 1), 1,
                     paste, collapse = "")
               )
           )

#        x group
# 1  adsad     2
# 2  assdf     4
# 3  gfdfg     3
# 4  vbcvb     1
# 5 dsXXfg     6
# 6 xxdsbc     5
# 7 dsfgbc     7
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
b<-rep(NA,length(x))

index<-grepl("ds", x)
b[index]<-rep(0,sum(index))

index_temp<-grepl("fg", x)
index<-((index_temp)*1+(is.na(b))*1)==2
b[index]<-rep(1,sum(index))

index_temp<-grepl("bc", x)
index<-((index_temp)*1+(is.na(b))*1)==2
b[index]<-rep(2,sum(index))
```

Comment: Can you explain the statement                                                               index_temp<-grepl("fg", x)
index<-((index_temp)*1+(is.na(b))*1)==2
b[index]<-rep(1,sum(index))

Comment: index_temp<-grepl("fg", x) gives all variables containing the string "fg". However, in your if/ else statement you said the value 1 should only be given to the vector b, if it does not contain "ds". That is the reason why I check if any other value has been given to b with (is.na(b)). If both conditions are met, I write 1 to this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely convinced about the solution but you can try following:

```
x <- c("adsad", "assdf", "gfdfg", "vbcvb","dsfgbc","agdsfg","dsbc","fgbc")

grepl("ds",x)*1 + grepl("fg",x)*3 + grepl("bc",x)*5
[1] 1 0 3 5 9 4 6 8
```

While the numbers should represent each unique combination, e.g

```
1 == ds
3 == fg
5 == bc
4 == ds & fg
6 == ds & bc
9 == ds & fg & bc
8 == fg & bc
```

This works because a logical vector is coerced into a numerical one if it is required. So `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`.